# How can I limit the CPU usage of solve()?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cpu

Whenever I run R's base-function `solve(A)`, with `A` being a large matrix, my R instance uses all 8 cores of my Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04) to 100 % so that my whole system is slowed down.

Is there a way to tell `solve()` how many cores it should use?

Alternative, is it possible to tell my R instance (from within R) to never use more than say 90 % of a core?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you some special matrix algebra library installed and linked with R?

Comment: You can renice your R session with this: `system(paste("renice -n 19 -p", Sys.getpid()))`

Comment: Could you add some information about your R session? Run `sessionInfo()` and paste your results. I wonder if like the above commenter mentioned, you have a particular matrix algebra library installed.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Indeed, I have the OpenBLAS library installed. Problem solved by installing the ```RhpcBLASctl``` package and then running ```blas_set_num_threads(6)```.